VScode remove the blue selection highlighter in the editor
Not sure what this is called but its the blue box that pops up whenever you click in various sections in the editor.  Any way to remove it?  Not sure why they would put something so annoying like that in by default.

Here is some filler text to describe the annoying blue box that pops up everywhere.

That is a focus indicator - important for accessibility reasons.  But you can effectively disable it in your settings.json by rendering it transparent:
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "focusBorder": "#0000"   // 4th hex digit is opacity
  }

